# Proof of equating coefficients validity in Catalan number formula derivation?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, recurrence-relations, catalan-numbers

Kindly find below the $5^{th}$ proof of Catalan formula from Wikipedia. After obtaining $2$ formulas for $B_{n+1}-C_{n+1}$, in this case why is it valid to say that $2B_i-C_i={2i+1\choose i}$? Although in general if we have $\sum_{i=0}^{n}x_iC_i=\sum_{i=0}^{n}y_iC_i$, this does not necessarily imply that $x_i=y_i$.

[image: Catalan formula 5th proof]

Comment: Is this older version better?  https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Catalan_number&oldid=1005702942#Fifth_proof  The article has been heavily edited by a semi-incompetent user Darcourse (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Darcourse) over the past 18 months; it is a lot of work to run around after him undoing the damage that he does.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JBL, I fully understand the version you posted.